# Excessive recrawl of ColdFusion dynamic pages

Tags: coldfusion

The folks who use ColdFusion and serversideincludes are having issues with excessive recrawls on dynamic pages because there is no datelastmodfied set, which causes excessive server traffic. You can laugh if you want, but when I tell them the solution is setting a last modified date on the pages I get a universal huh? how do you do that? I opened a case with google originally and was told that yep, it's a page date problem. I have done a lot of research to try and find how to code this in the header and most of what I found talked about pulling a date from a page.
I did determine that it probably could be done using the `CFHEADER` tag. I'm just not sure about implementing. 
Can I tell them that adding something like

```
<cfheader NAME="datelastmodified="Mon, 01 Feb 2013 08:00:00 GMT">
```

will suffice? Not sure about the date format, if the day name is required.
Have I tried just asking one of the webmasters to try this? No I haven't. I would like to know that I am at least on the right track before taking up too much of their time. And so far none of them have come up with a solution on their own other than useing robots.txt to block the crawl or things along those lines.
Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Fortunately, none of these things need to be mysterious, as they're all well documented.

- [last-modified HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29)
- [HTTP date/time formats](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3)
- [`<cfheader>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7aea.html)
- and even a function to format the date correctly: [`getHttpTimeString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6dd3.html)

This all comes together to suggest this sort of thing:

```
<cfheader name="Last-Modified" value="#getHttpTimeString(now())#"> <!--- although use some timestamp indicating when the content of the page was last updated,which would be a system-specific sort of thing --->
```

NB: I didn't know any of the specifics to this until I googled it about 5min ago.

Answer (score 1):

Google's crawlers do tend to respect the meta tag details and HTTP response values for pages they encounter and the way to set such in CF is indeed with the CFHEADER tag. You'll want to craft it to look something like this:

```
<CFHEADER NAME="Last-Modified" VALUE="#DateFormat(now (), 'ddd, dd mmm yyyy')#   #TimeFormat(now(), 'HH:mm:ss')# GMT#gmt#">
<CFHEADER NAME="Expires" VALUE="Mon, 10 Mar 2013 05:00:00 GMT">
```

You will likely want a CF dev to do that work as I'm showing you two examples for the datetime value there. The first one dynamically sets it to right now (using the DateFormat() and Now() functions) and the second example sets the Expires header value with a hard coded date.

You'll probably want to include both the last-modified and expires tags and decide whether you want the dates applied to each to be either dynamic or hard coded.